# Why isn't there a ";" after "do" in sh loops?

Tags: shell

Why isn't there a `;` character after `do` in shell loops when written on a single line?

Here's what I mean. When written on a multiple lines, a `for` loop looks like:

```
$ for i in $(jot 2)
> do
>     echo $i
> done
```

And on a single line:

```
$ for i in $(jot 2); do echo $i; done
```

All the collapsed lines get a `;` after them *except* for the `do` line, and if you include the `;`, it is an error. Someone probably a heck of a lot smarter than me decided that this was the right thing to do for a reason, but I can't figure out what the reason is. It seems inconsistent to me.

The same with `while` loops too.

```
$ while something
> do
>     anotherthing
> done
$ while something; do anotherthing; done
```

Comment: Related: [Semicolon in conditional structures](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/48805)

Comment: It is consistent: there's no semicolon after `while` / `for` either.

Comment: The thing that immediately comes to mind is that it's just not necessary. Elsewhere, the semicolons distinguish the statements.

Comment: Because it would be redundant. There is no ambiguity without it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is the syntax of the command.  See [Compound Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands)

```
for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

Note specifically:  `do commands`

Most people put the `do` and `commands` on a separate line to allow for easier readability but it is not necessary, you could write:

```
for i in thing
do something
done
```

I know this question is specifically about shell and I have linked to the bash manual. It is not written that way in the shell manual but it is written that way in an [article written by Stephen Bourne](https://archive.org/stream/byte-magazine-1983-10/1983_10_BYTE_08-10_UNIX#page/n193/mode/2up) for byte magazine.

Stephen says:

> A *command list* is a sequence of one or more simple commands separated or terminated by a newline or `;` (semicolon). Furthermore, reserved words like *do* and *done* are normally preceded by a newline or `;`... In turn each time the command list following *do* is executed.

Comment: It would be also interesting why there **must not** be a semicolon, like `for i in thing; do; something; done`. Altough a line break is allowed, a semicolon is not allowed.

Comment: @gidds: yes, exactly.  That's how shell grammar is structured, too.  The `something` is the subject and `do` applies to it.  Just like in the English sentence structure.

Comment: @gidds A literal (or some other piece of syntax) is necessary because multiple commands can go in the condition (in the `while` syntax), so you need something to differentiate the condition commands from the loop body commands. Using `do` to separate them is probably what simply seemed most fitting.

Comment: @rexkogitans Indeed, I never realized that was a syntax error. This title question is very fitting for that, too. It probably has to do with not allowing an empty body. You get a slightly different syntax error when making an empty body with newlines, though, and your example doesn't have an empty body.

Comment: @rexkogitans The semicolon here is part of the loop syntax and distinct from its other role as a command-list terminator. The newline is different because if it isn't otherwise required or expected, it is treated like ordinary whitespace. Shell grammar is messy.

Comment: For me, it makes me wonder what 'do' is for.   But I know the answer now that I started typing this:  'do' is like a '{' and 'done' is like a '}'.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know what the original reason for this syntax is, but let's consider the fact that `while` loops can take multiple commands in the condition section, e.g.

```
while a=$(somecmd);
      [ -n "$a" ];
do
    echo "$a"
done
```

Here, the `do` keyword is necessary to tell apart the condition section and main body of the loop. `do` is a keyword like `while`, `if` and `then` (and `done`), and it seems to be in line with the others that it doesn't require a semicolon or newline after it but appears immediately before a command.

The alternative (generalized to `if` and `while`) would look somewhat ugly, we'd need to write e.g.

```
if; [ -n "$a" ]; then
    some command here
fi
```

The syntax of `for` loops is just similar.

Answer (score 13):

Shell syntax is prefix based. It has clauses introduced by special keywords. Certain clauses have to go together.

A `while` loop is made out one or more testing commands:

```
test ; test ; test ; ...
```

and by one or more body commands:

```
body ; body ; body ; ...
```

Something has to tell the shell that a while loop begins. That's the purpose of the `while` word:

```
while test ; test ; test ; ...
```

But then, things are ambiguous. Which command is the start of the body? Something has to indicate that, and that's what the `do` prefix does:

```
do body ; body ; body ; ...
```

and, finally, something has to indicate that the last body has been seen; a special keyword  `done` does that.

These shell keywords don't require semicolon separation, even on the same line. For instance, if you close several nested loops, you can just have `done done done ...`.

Rather, the semicolon is between `... test ; body ...`  if they are on the same line. That semicolon is understood to be a terminator: it belongs with the `test`. Therefore, if a `do` keyword is inserted between them, it has to go between the semicolon and `body`. If it were on the other side of the semicolon, it would be wrongly embedded inside the `test` command's syntax, rather than placed between commands.

The shell syntax was originally designed by Stephen Bourne, and is inspired by [Algol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL#Examples_and_portability_issues). Bourne loved Algol so much that he used lots of C macros in the shell source code to make C look like Algol. You can [browse the 1979-dated shell sources from Version 7 Unix](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh). The macros are in `mac.h`, and they are used all over the place. For instance `if` statements are rendered as `IF` ... `ELSE` ... `ELIF` ... `FI`.

Comment: The source code is impressive.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tour de force of cpp.

Answer (score 7):

I'd argue that `do` is not particularly special here. You get an error because `;` cannot start a command list. If it did, the first command would be empty, and grammar does not allow empty commands (variable assignments or redirections without a command, yes, but absolutely nothing, no). This is true in any number of places, wherever a list of commands is expected:

```
$ while true; do ; echo foo; done
dash: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
$ while ; true; do; echo; done
dash: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
$ { ; echo foo; }
dash: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
$ if ; true; then echo foo; fi
dash: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

Even:

```
$ ; ;
dash: 1: Syntax error: ";" unexpected
```

In all of these places, a command list is expected, and so a leading `;` is unexpected.

Comment: Yeah - the way I arbitrarily added a '\n' after 'do' made me think that 'do' was a stand-alone token and not something that operated on the block that follows.

Comment: How is it that a non-escaped newline (which otherwise seems to behave just like a semicolon in shell syntax) _is_ allowed after `do` (and `if` etc), though?

Comment: @Henning  Any number of newlines are allowed before (and after) a command list. Newlines and semicolons behave differently in other aspects, too. For example, alias expansion is done when a whole line of input is read (i.e., up to the next newline), and not per command.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
for i in [whitespace separated list of values]
do [newline separated list of commands]
done
```

Any of the newlines, either in the command list or before the "do" or "done" can be replaced by a ";".

A newline (but not a ";") is *allowed* after the "do" and before the "in", just to make things look nicer, but it wouldn't make sense to *require* a newline there.

Answer (score 3):

`if` is similar with its keywords: this is quite readable when the commands are short:

```
if   test_commands
then true_commands
else false_commands
fi
```

Comment: Once I realized I was putting in an arbitrary `\n` after `do` it all made sense  (as long as you don't think about *not* being able to put in an arbitrary `\n` between other commands and args).

Comment: Well, `do`, `then`, `else` are not **args** -- if they were, you would not be allowed to use a semicolon before them. They are **shell keywords** (see `type if then elif else fi`)

Comment: I guess I wasn't as clear as I wanted to be on my reply.

Comment: My point was that "do" is not like any "other command". So it obeys different rules.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, because this is specified by [POSIX shell grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02). Anything between `do` and `done` is considered a group of statements, while `;` is sequential separator :

```
for_clause       : For name                                      do_group
                 | For name                       sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in          sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group

do_group         : Do compound_list Done 

sequential_sep   : ';' linebreak
                 | newline_list
```

Additionally, if `;` were necessary the standard would explicitly state so and would include `sequential_sep` after `Do`.

Comment: @drewbenn You mean the very first one ? That is iterating through positional parameters. So if you have a script called like ./myscript.sh a b c, where a b c are arguments, the loop for i ; do echo "$i" ; done would loop through a b c, though I still think it would need semicolon for it to work

Comment: Ok, so my doubts are cleared as well

Answer (score 1):

Because do is a keyword and what follows it are essentially parameters. The Bash interpreter knows that more follows.   It's similar to how there is no ';' following the i in the for command.  You can actually add a newline after the i in for and type the rest on a new line and it will work fine.